# Installing a python package via GIT from within Ansible collection

Tags: python, ansible, python-module, requirements.txt, ansible-collections

I'm creating an Ansible collection. The collection has dependencies defined within the `requirements.txt`. In previous projects I've used `module_utils` to have my private Python libraries within the collection. No I'd like to have my private Python packages installed automatically during the installation of the collection itself. Therefore, I've added the Git repository of my python package to the `requirements.txt` of the Ansible collection.

## Ansible collection Repository

```
├── README.md
├── galaxy.yml
├── plugins
│   ├── module_utils
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── modules
│       └── __init__.py
│       └── mymodule1.py
└── requirements.txt
```

The requirements are pointing to the repository, where my Python package is hosted.

`requirements.txt`

```
requests
jinja2
yaml
git+https://my.git.server/python.package@master#egg=mypythonpackage
```

## `mypythonpackage` Repository

```
├── README.md
├── VERSION
├── mypythonpackage
│   ├── PyPackage.py
│   ├── __init__.py
├── pyproject.toml
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
```

In my Ansible project I create a `requirements.yml`, which points to the Git repository of the Ansible collection. I install the collection(s) via

```
ansible-galaxy collection install -r requirements.yml
```

This works fine and correctly. All Python dependencies, from `requirements.txt` (from within the collection) are installed correctly, except for my Python package `mypythonpackage` via Git. It's just ignored. Even when installing with `-vvvv` there is not output related to my package.

Any ideas?